# Managing Database with SQL Server and Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, azure-data-studio

I'm working with a group on an ASP.NET Core MVC project. We are developing a web application which needs to connect to a database.

But we are unsure how we can connect to the database.

One member is using Windows - SQL Server and the other use MAC - Azure Data Studio. Is this going to affect us in any side later on? And we are developing using (code-first approach) how we can start the connection and building our database?

Comment: I suggest finding a tutorial... its too large a question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is work on creating your Models and your Database Context, you also need to set up a connection string to connect to your database. I'm assuming that you are setting a local database on your machine to develop on, you'll need to install SQL Server first.

Once you do, you don't need to create a database (You could if you want to), as the migration will create the database for you.

After you get your SQL Server install and your solution set up with the database context, you can run your migrations, and update the database.

Once you do that, you can use either SSMS or Azure Data Studio. Azure Data Studio can be used on both Windows and Mac and is really great. I almost exclusively use it now.